# Bootstrap Grid when/why two options in col attribute (eg. col-md-1-12)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

New to bootstrap and I seem to grasp the logic behind the grid system but I've seen a few examples of col attributes using 2 numbers instead of 1.

eg. `col-md-1-12` vs `col-md-12`

I have not been able to find any explanation of what this means or does?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: <div class = "row">
<div class="col-md-2">
</div>
</div>

Comment: `col-md-1-12` is not a Bootstrap class. If you saw this it was a custom implementation.